# Imported scene in Aframe with gltf-part resets object origins to 0,0,0

Tags: blender, aframe, gltf

Problem: The origins of objects used with gltf-part are at 0,0,0

codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-moore-4383f?file=/index.html

> shows a log with the correct positions when displayed as a scene and one where I use gltf-part to show the cubes where all positions of the cubes are at 0,0,0

The exported scene is from blender, in which I set the origin to the center of each cube, see the top right cube.

After importing the gltf file in Aframe, and showing the cubes with gltf-part, every cube has as origin 0,0,0.

The GLTF is correct, when I import it again in blender, the origins are still at the center of the cube.

[image: Blender file origin of top right cube is in center, even after export to gltf and imported again]
[image: Aframes inspector shows origin of all cubes and selected top right cube is 0,0,0]

How can I get the correct coordinates of each cube in Aframe if they are all at position 0,0,0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is behaving as expected, the parts are selected but you're still loading them as a child in your scene so their relative positions are retained at 0,0,0 for the parent element.

Here is a rough outline of how to change this behavior to meet your needs:

- You will need to edit the `gltf-part` component to "reset" the position of the "part" that it extracts when it is loaded. After the mesh is cloned in this line:
  `mesh = part.getObjectByProperty('type', 'Mesh').clone(true);`
  then you'll want to copy the position of that mesh to a variable and then also reset the mesh locally:
  `mesh.position.set ( 0, 0, 0 );`
- Then you'll want to set the A-Frame entity to the position that you've just saved in the variable.

Here is example code with a modified component: https://codesandbox.io/s/gltf-part-reset-qgovf note the renamed component to `gltf-part-reset` and the new attribute `resetPosition`. The default is `false` to retain existing `gltf-part` behavior, set to `true` in this example to exhibit desired behavior.

Comment: That works. Nice solution, don't know why this isn't the default behaviour. Or is this not common practice?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
  window.addEventListener("model-loaded", (e) => {
    const sceneObj = document.querySelector("a-scene").object3D;
    let object;
    object = sceneObj.getObjectByProperty("name", "cube1");
    console.log(object.position);
    object = sceneObj.getObjectByProperty("name", "cube2");
    console.log(object.position);
  });
```

Comment: I tried that just now and that seems to work if I use the gltf-model. I noticed I forgot to mention I use gltf-part to show the different cubes. After using gltf-part all origins of the 3 cubes are 0,0,0. I'll edit the post and include a link to a code sample including your snippet which indeeds shows the correct position on the complete model but resets to 0,0,0 when using gltf-part